# Responsive design with CSS3

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I used to work with responsive design. Now I have a feeling, but not sure, that it is possible to manage the position of each div by its id or class. For example:

```
<div id='first'></div>
<div id='second'></div>
<div id='third'></div>
```

In CSS you might be able to say:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
     // pseudo code
     #second: after #third
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
     // pseudo code
     #first: after #third
}
```

Is it possible to manage the element that way without giving the position a value, left or right a value?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with flexbox using the `order` property.

### **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hoq4zkwz/1/)** (Resize browser window)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.first {
  background: gold;
}
.second {
  background: tomato;
}
.third {
  background: aqua;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .second {
    order: 3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .second {
    order: 1;
  }
}
.first {
  order: 3;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">first</div>
  <div class="second">second</div>
  <div class="third">third</div>
</div>
```

Check out [this css-tricks articl](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)e for an overview of flexbox.